# Form Post with RequestBuilder

Tags: java, gwt

What is the correct way to do a `RequestBuilder` in GWT to be able to do exactly what this does for plain HTML:

```
<form action="javascript:;" method="post" data-field="form">
      <input class="rounded" name="username" size="20" type="text" data-field="username">
      <input class="rounded" name="password" size="20" type="password" data-field="password">
      <button class="submit" type="submit" value="Login" data-field="button"><br>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you can wrap each input with gwt widgets, in the case of large forms it is better to iterate over all form elements, read their names and values, and produce a query-string to send as data with your requestBuilder, this code should work:

```java
  String payload = "";
  Element e = DOM.getElementById("form");
  // you need make this recursive if you want grand-children
  for (int i = 0, l = e.getChildCount(); i < l; i++) {
    Element c = e.getChild(i).cast();
    if (c.getTagName().toLowerCase().matches("input")) {
      String name = c.<InputElement>cast().getName();
      String value = c.<InputElement>cast().getValue();
      payload += name + "=" + value + "&";
    }
  }

  RequestBuilder b = new RequestBuilder(POST, "/my_servlet");
  try {
    b.sendRequest(payload, new RequestCallback() {
      public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
         String resp = response.getText();
      }
      public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
      }
    });
  } catch (RequestException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
  }
```

But, I prefer to make use of the [gwtquery](https://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/) slogan: (`do more, write less`):

```java
  Properties data = Properties.create();
  // This loop also gets grand-children, and you can use more sophisticated css selectors
  for (Element e: $("form").find("input").elements()) {
    data.set($(e).attr("name"), $(e).val());
  }

  GQuery.post("/my_servlet", data, new Function(){
    public void f(){
      // Use getDataObjet in non snapshot versions
      String response = arguments(0);
    };
  });
```

Comment: arguments(0) is causing compile-time error, is it a method of Function()?

Comment: Did you mean getDataObject()?

Comment: getDataObject is deprecated in gQuery 1.4.0-SNAPSHOT in favor of arguments to make the code looks closed to jQuery.

Comment: Then I must be using the old version X_X

Comment: BTW, the properties transparently handles primitive types right? I mean I have a Jax-rs resource which will accept this and that it is bound to accept a custom @Form class which have a boolean field? in the RequestBuilder way I had to explicitly convert the boolen to String during the get method of the "boolean" field...

Comment: Yes it does. Actually Properties is just a GWT overlay type so it wraps a native js object which you could cast to any other overlay type. You have helper methods to getBoolean, setBoolean etc. gQuery is plenty of helper methods to deal with js without writing jsni.

Comment: Actually 1.3.3 is not an old version, it is the stable one and it was released just few days ago, but we are working hard in the snapshot to release nice things, like better Function object, implementation of Deferred and Promises in GWT, and other cool things.

Answer (score 2):

**First build a request like below(psuedocode):**

```
RequestBuilder req= new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.POST, url);
req.setHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");


StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(URL.encodeComponent("usename="+usernameVal+"&"));
sb.append(URL.encodeComponent("password="+passwordval));//add & if more params.


req.setRequestData(sb.toString());
req.setCallback(new RequestCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
           //TO DO
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
        }
    });
```

**In Submit button click handler:**

```
try {
       req.send();
    }
catch (Exception e){
       e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```

They are bit old but for reference: [RequestBuilderUsage](http://www.androidadb.com/class/re/RequestBuilder.html) and [GeetingResponse through GWT HTTP](http://www.javabeat.net/2011/03/getting-response-through-gwt-using-http-protocol/).

*I hope the above few lines will give some basic idea*